# Integrating responsive webdesign with lot of background-images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position, responsive

I'm new to front integrations with images.

**How could I create one of the two panels in the following picture that would keep texts, buttons and headings at the right position when the user stretches the window ?**

I thought about different approaches to accomplish it:

> Using a single picture as a background and relatively positioning texts for heading, content and clickable area of the panel as absolute divs.

> Or cutting heading, button and panel images and make them divs with their respective background-image and position the div themselves with text inside them.

Here is a picture of the result I would like to achieve:

[image]

Images I got:

Full panel:

[image]

And I have also the banner, the background and the button separately.

Maybe there's another way to integrate I didn't think about ?

Every approaches is welcome :)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: How is it not answerable ? I present two choices I thought to implement and asking what would be the best way to implement that. So I won't spend time doing a wrong approach

Comment: "Best" is asking for opinions and so is not suitable for SO.

Comment: Now that's an information I would love to read on your original comment.... --"

Comment: So is it just a matter of words ? If I would have asked for the more optimized way of doing it you wouldn't have downvoted my post ???? Seriously....

Comment: We don't "optimize" code either, thats what CodeReview.Se is for.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your image and added a header, description and a button. The positioning can be done very easily. The container with flex is for the responsive design (the divs wrap). Run code snippet and resize the window to see:

```css
/* Padding: 0; for no padding in the edges */

* {
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #654321;
}

/*
  This content is for the mobile version START
*/

.image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
}

.imageHeader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.imageText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.imageButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 1.5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
height: auto;
}

/*
  This content is for the mobile version END
*/

/*
  media only screen with min-width for mobile first! 
  
  The code below is for the Computer Version!!!
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {

.image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
}

.imageHeader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.imageText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.imageButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 3.5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
img {
height: 500px;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="image">
    <h2 class="imageHeader">Header</h2>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHqR7m.png">
    <p class="imageText">Description</p>
    <button class="imageButton">Buy $2.99</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image">
    <h2 class="imageHeader">Header</h2>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHqR7m.png">
    <p class="imageText">Description</p>
    <button class="imageButton">Buy $2.99</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks dude ;)
Didn't know this flex value from display property !

Comment: Hey ! Achieved like a charm what I wanted to do, thanks :) Just wanted to know if there's a way for only two panels in large laptop screens to display bigger, actually the size of the "image" div is two times bigger than the actual image. I tried everything !
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I edited the answer a bit. On the computer version the pictures are a bit bigger than before (Click on **full page** in the snippet and resize the window to see!). In the mobile version, the image is slightly smaller (if you don't want this, you can remove the `@media` part). 

**If there are things you don't like, please let me know ;)**

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? :o

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! Happy coding! :D

Comment: Such wolesomeness <3

Comment: Happy coding to you too :)

Comment: Hey ! How could I set the .imageText to be start aligned vertically please ? Actually it is centered vertically.

Comment: And the .imageBackground is not displayed well (way too large) starting at big phone. And also I have a blank space in th right of my page... I suck so much at css this is crazy :'(

Comment: Fixed the right blank space. But the .image block as a height of 1153px in phones... What am I missing please ?

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't really understand it. Can you show me a picture of the problem please?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://ibb.co/F3zrRQR
The result is the same in all phones viewports with chrome devtools. Tablets and more are OK. I checked with your snippet and this is definitely not the same behavior.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/54ab4afc3293ce17d07211abfd5d799020210227205047/472776 here is a wetransfer with my code, I made some changes to fit my needs, maybe I forgot somehting, I understand nothing with flexboxes....

Comment: What country do u live in ? I would send you some homebrew for your patience :D

Comment: Can you please send me the URL of your website? I don't have access to wetransfer.com. I hope I can help you as much as possible! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I live in Germany. But thanks for inviting me :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229319/discussion-between-guccibananaking99-and-pierrick-martelliere).

Comment: Hey, I entered in the chat and sent you the sources :) I could send some beer to Germany for you ! :D